# Cannot locate resource in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have 2 assembly projects and I am trying to reference BooksGrid in the Library.Books project From Library.UI assembly project  but I keep 
Getting the following Exception  “ Cannot locate resource  ‘grid/booksgridlist.xaml” but the file exists as explained below.
I have tried almost everything as explained in other similar questions but nothing worked. am i doing something wrong ? Any help is well appreciated in advance.

BooksGrid.cs  in Library.Books Assembly project . Note:  BooksGridList.xaml is resource file located in this same project.
Absolute Path for BooksGrid.cs:  C:\Library.Books\Grids\BooksGrid.cs
Absolute Path for BooksGridList.xaml:  C:\Library.Books\Grids\BooksGridList.xaml  and build 
action for this file is set to “Resource” and Copy to output Directory is set to “Do not Copy”  -- I also tried "copy always" but that did not work. I cleaned the project and build it again but still it did not work.

```
namespace Library.Books.Grids
{
  public class BooksGrid
  { 
    public BooksGrid()
    {
        AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        CanUserAddRows = false;
        IsReadOnly = true;
    ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary
        {
            Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Library.Books;component/Grids/BooksGridList.xaml")
        };
   } 
  }
}
```

BooksSelector.xaml  in   Library.UI  assembly project
Absolute Path for BooksSelector.xaml:  C:\Library.UI\Library.UI.BooksSelector

```
<UserControl x:Class=" Library.UI.BooksSelector" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource=    {RelativeSource Self}}" 
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ex="clr-namespace:Library.Books.Grids;assembly=Library.Books"
         xmlns:dx="clr-namespace:Library.Sections.Converters;assembly=Library.Sections">
<UserControl.Resources>
  <dx:FormattingConverter x:Key="ValueConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
 <ex:BooksGrid Name="LibraryCtrl" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="2"   SelectionChanged="LibraryCtrl_OnSelectionChanged"  PropertyChanged="LibraryCtrl_OnPropertyChanged">
   <ex:BooksGrid.Columns >
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="100" Header="ISBN" SortMemberPath="ISBN" Binding="{Binding Path=ISBN}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="180" Header="Name" SortMemberPath="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Collapsed" Width="70" Header="LibraryCode" SortMemberPath="LibraryCode" Binding="{Binding Path=LibraryCode}" />                
   </ex:BooksGrid.Columns>
  </ex:BooksGrid>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3):

Why you are not doing this in xaml.

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Library.Books;component/Grids/BooksGridList.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: do you mean the xaml ( Library.UI.BooksSelector ) ? if yes, wouldn't that mean the resource on Library.UI assembly instead of the referenced assembly ( Library.Books ) ?

Comment: I mean in your Usercontrol.xaml, in which you want to apply this style. You can add this in your MainWindow also.In that case you have to <Window.Resources> instead of <UserControl.Resources>.

Comment: Source="{application name};component/{path to resource with extension}"